# Error message in linux's dmesg: eno1: Detected Hardware Unit Hang

Tags: ubuntu, networking

[image: photo with error here]

- Could somebody tell me whats that error means?
- Is it serious problem or not really?
- Or how to diagnose it?
- Could that be related with my network? Seems that my router also got stuck in the same time.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 on i5-2400, 4gb ram, hdd.
CPU usually isn't going above 50%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

> Could somebody tell me whats that error means?

The complete answer on this question requires the deep knowledge in several disciplines: digital hardware design, system programming, linux kernel design and some other. The simple variant of the answer can be sound like 'something has going wrong while the NIC was transmitting the packet'

> Is it serious problem or not really?

This error causes the network disconnect on your PC.

> Or how to diagnose it?

You already know how to diagnose it - by checking the logs (commands `dmesg` or better `journalctl -k`)

> Could that be related with my network? Seems that my router also got stuck in the same time.

This issue related only your linux system. I think your router is fine. It's your PC losts connection to network, include the connectivity with the router.

This is a known issue. Almost always it's a driver related problem. You can try to install the e1000e driver from the [intel site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/14611/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-pcie-intel-gigabit-ethernet-network-connections-under-linux.html) or update the kernel. If it won't help try to disable the offloads (details in the `man ethtool`). Otherwise use the other network adapter (based on intel i350 NIC).

Comment: okey thanks alot, ill just wait if this happen again and ill try to diagnose it. For now ill just do what you said with updatingthe driver. Thanks!